# Ruby on Rails - prefixing the application URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, scope, routes

I've built a Ruby on Rails application using 2 scaffolds, generating models named posts and comments such that a post has_many comments and each comment belongs_to a post. My application's main page, "posts#index," can be accessed in the browser at the URL

> localhost:3000/posts

Comments are a nested resource for posts:

```
resources :posts do
    resources :comments
end
```

I want to change my routes.rb so that I access my application `localhost:3000/foo/bar/posts`

So far I've managed to accomplish half the task, but I can't find information to finish it. I've found that I can access my application at `localhost:3000/foo/posts` with the following:

```
scope :path => 'foo' do
   resources :posts do
      resources :comments
   end

   resources :comments
end
```

Substituting 'foo/bar' for 'foo' in the above routes.rb snippet unfortunately doesn't get the job done.

Any ideas? Thanks for looking!

Comment: I'm looking for a simple fix. Maybe a few lines in the routes.rb that can accomplish this url change. The rails installation is otherwise typical, and I'd like to minimize changes to other files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was really looking for a simple fix--something I could do without making little changes in the rails app that I'd have to keep track of.

What I ended up doing was manually re-routing in the routes.rb file, e.g.

```
get '/foo/bar/posts' as 'posts#index'
```

That did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to have everything in a subdirectory, set `config.action_controller.relative_url_root = '/foo'` in your `config/application.rb` file. This would happen if you're deploying to a subdirectory on a server with passenger.

If it's just a few things in a typical Rails deployment what you want is to use a namespace. For example, if you put this in your `routes.rb`:

```
namespace :foo do
  namespace :bar do
    resources :posts
  end
end
```

You would then create an `Foo::Bar::PostsController` in `app/controllers/foo/bar//posts_controller.rb`. Foo::Bar::PostsController's index action would be  accessible from `/foo/bar/posts`.

See [Rails Routing from the Outside in: 2.6 Controller Namespaces and Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing) for more info.

Comment: What would be the content in Admin::PostsController?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is make the URL localhost:3000/foo/bar/posts. What I have now is localhost:3000/foo/posts.

Comment: @user1489878 I have updated the answer to make it more clear.

Comment: What modifications do I make to accommodate the namespace solution? Create directories /foo/bar/ in my app/controllers/ and copy the posts controller to that directory?